# Count number of farming households per district

Tags: sqlite

I have census data in the following columns:

FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, OCCUPATION, HOUSEHOLD_ID, DISTRICT, COUNTY

And some sample data:

```
Anne, Boyle, Student, 7090989, Green Acres, Coolidge 
John, Boyle, Farmer, 7090989, Green Acres, Coolidge  
Mary, Boyle, Farmer's wife, 7090989, Green Acres, Coolidge  
James, Egan, Carpenter, 1090933, Green Acres, Coolidge
Margret, Egan, Teacher, 1090933, Green Acres, Coolidge
William, Dunne, Merchant, 2090921, Falls, Cleveland
Anne, Smyth, Widow, 1110166, Range, Cleveland
Daniel, McCann, Farm labourer, 1011112, Griffin, Cleveland
Timothy, McCann, Farm labourer, 1011112, Griffin, Cleveland
Patrick, Sullivan, Farmer, 2217733, Ards, Cleveland
Maggie, Sullivan, Farmer, 2217733, Ards, Cleveland
Michael, Petterson, Farmer labourer, 2227229, Ards, Cleveland
```

So I wish to count the number of farming households per district. Each household has a unique id and a single farming household is defined as a household with at least one occupant with an occupation `LIKE "%Farm%"`. So the number of farmers in the household is not of interest, just whether there is at least one farmer. For the data above I should get the following result:

```
Green Acres, Coolidge, 1
Griffin, Cleveland, 1
Ards, Cleveland, 2
```

This is how I establish the number of farmers per district:

```
Select DISTRICT, COUNTY, COUNT(*) from census where OCCUPATION like "%Farm%" group by DISTRICT, COUNTY;
```

To get the number of households per district I do:

```
select DISTRICT, COUNTY, COUNT(distinct(HOUSEHOLD_ID)) from census group by DISTRICT, COUNTY;
```

So how do I count the number of farming households per district.

**UPDATE**

```
A county is made up of uniquely named districts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I count the number of farming households per district

This means grouping by `DISTRICT`:

```
select DISTRICT,
count(distinct HOUSEHOLD_ID) counter
from census 
where OCCUPATION like 'Farm%'
group by DISTRICT;
```

If you also want the `COUNTY` column:

```
select 
  COUNTY, 
  DISTRICT,
  count(distinct HOUSEHOLD_ID) from census 
where OCCUPATION like 'Farm%' 
group by COUNTY, DISTRICT
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/doaQsXXWeWSBjCd9W5KbDn/0)

Comment: Why not?: "select COUNTY, DISTRICT,count(distinct HOUSEHOLD_ID) from census where OCCUPATION like 'Farm%' group by COUNTY, DISTRICT;"

Comment: *A county is made up of uniquely named districts* then fine you can do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT a.DISTRICT,
   a.COUNTY,
   COUNT(*) 
   FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT(b.HOUSEHOLD_ID),
       b.DISTRICT,
       b.COUNTY FROM census b
       WHERE b.OCCUPATION like '%FARM%'
   ) as a
   GROUP BY
   a.DISTRICT,
   a.COUNTY
```